# Selecting Data in my sdf file is very slow

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'am working on application on symbol Motorola device, with Windows ce 5.0 version, and I try to read a query from the "sdf" database with a simple select command. 
but the result came very very slow.

this is my code

```
private SqlCeConnection myCn;
private SqlCeCommand cm;
private SqlCeDataReader dr;

myCn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=\Storage Card\PDT_Data.sdf;Max Database Size=4091;Max Buffer Size = 1024;Default Lock Escalation =100;");
cm = myCn.CreateCommand();
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MainInputFile WHERE BARCODE = " +  txtBarCode;
dr = null;
if (myCn.State != ConnectionState.Open) myCn.Open();
dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
 txtBarCode.Text = dr["BARCODE"].ToString();
 txtItemInformation.Text = dr["DESCRIPTION"].ToString();
 txtItemInformation.Text += "\r\n" + dr["BYUM"].ToString();
 txtItemInformation.Text += "\r\n" + dr["ITEMSKU"].ToString();
 txtItemInformation.Text += "\r\n" + dr["SALEPRIC"].ToString();
}
```

please any one can help me.

Comment: How many rows are inside the db? Have you tried copy pasting files from the \Storage Card\ to another location? Also, your code seems to continuously overwrite the textbox(?) for each row, UI operation is expensive, you might want to just store them into CSV, array or other DB instead of displaying them into the textbox.

Comment: it's about 152284 row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding index to your compact database, its actually easy:

```
string command = "Create NONCLUSTERED INDEX BARCODE_INDEX ON MainInputFile(BARCODE)";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(command, GetConnection());
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Database operations on devices are usually expensive, if you have a lot of data be sure to add index properly.

Also as Martheen pointed: separate your DB operations from UI.